# Get longitude and latitude from API

Tags: c#, ssis, bing-api

I have searched on Google and here on Stack Overflow, but due to my limited expertise in C# and SSIS I have some troubles getting through.

My steps in this SSIS package is as follows:

1. I have a SQL task connected to a for loop which only specifies how many times I should iterate in Forloop container which is =1
2. Inside Forloop container have a dataflow task
3. In dataflow task, I use an OLEDB source to get addresses from a SQL table
4. I connect those OLEDB source to a Script task from which the following script "Should" return my XML answer from which I want to return Latitude and longitude. It does not return the answer that I want.

Example address is - Beihinger Strasse 160 DE-71726 BENNINGEN GERMANY

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        string url = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?addressLine={0}&output=xml&key={1}";
        var Address = Row.Address;
        var wGet = WebRequest.Create(String.Format(url, Address, Variables.APIkey));
        wGet.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        var response = wGet.GetResponse();
        var status = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
        Console.WriteLine("Input: " + Address);

        if (status == "OK")
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();

            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(responseFromServer);
            var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("Point", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1");
            var latNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/ResourceSets/ResourceSet/Resources/Location/Point/Latitude", nsmgr);
            var lngNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/ResourceSets/ResourceSet/Resources/Location/Point/Longitude", nsmgr);


            if (latNode != null && lngNode != null)
            {
                var numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." };
                Row.Latitude = decimal.Parse(latNode.InnerText, numberFormatInfo);
                Row.Longitude = decimal.Parse(lngNode.InnerText, numberFormatInfo);
                Row.FullResponse = responseFromServer.ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                //Set to null
                Row.Latitude_IsNull = true;
                Row.Longitude_IsNull = true;
                Row.FullResponse = responseFromServer.ToString();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Set to null
            Row.Latitude_IsNull = true;
            Row.Longitude_IsNull = true;
            Row.FullResponse_IsNull = true;
        }
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

**The response I get is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1"><Copyright>Copyright © 2020 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.</Copyright><BrandLogoUri>http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png</BrandLogoUri><StatusCode>200</StatusCode><StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription><AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode><TraceId>b9a94b411dc246ea82d161dae5e7a0c3|DU00000D73|0.0.0.1|Ref A: ACDD23537F6649F6B2F66333BB6D6D01 Ref B: DB3EDGE0918 Ref C: 2020-02-12T11:25:05Z</TraceId><ResourceSets><ResourceSet><EstimatedTotal>0</EstimatedTotal><Resources /></ResourceSet></ResourceSets></Response>
```

**I want a correct call as I get when using URL so I can get Longitude and Latitude**- [http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?addressLine=Beihinger%20Strasse%20160%20DE-71726%20BENNINGEN%20GERMANY&output=xml&key={APIkey}](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?addressLine=Beihinger%20Strasse%20160%20DE-71726%20BENNINGEN%20GERMANY&output=xml&key=%7BAPIkey%7D)

**Any help would be greatly appreciated to what I am missing?**

Comment: API from google requires you do get a key from google for application to run.  The second like is not returning a latitude and location and give warning message.  You will notice the URL on the webpage ends with "Key=".  You need to send the key to get a response.

Comment: @jdweng I am sorry for the confusion. I choose to write it out as Key={1} because i dont want to show my personal APIKey and they key is therefore specifiied as a variable in this case. var wGet = WebRequest.Create(String.Format(url, Address, Variables.APIkey) wich is created in the SSIS package as a variable aswell.

Comment: API may limit only one request at a time.  The WebRequest default headers may be wrong.  Usually I recommend using a sniffer and compare first request headers that work (like using Posstman) with non working.  Then modify the non working to look like working.  Usually it is the Content Type which is the default IE on machine.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for your answers! Dont know if i understand your answer to the fullest but i have specified in the SSIS package to parse only the row as abowe that do work which i have tried by buidling the URL and test which works.

Comment: @jdweng i used Postman to check my headers and it does seem like it works just fine im afraid.  Could it be something perhaps regarding the data type from my input column [Addresses]? datatype right now is nvarchar((max), null) in sql db and i convert this column in SSIS by derived column to LTRIM((DT_WSTR,50)Address)

Comment: If the address works in postman than is should also work in the WebRequest.  Using the sniffer you can compare the header in the request to see if they match.  The sniffer will indicate what is different an what need to be changed.

Comment: I'd change this line: var wGet = WebRequest.Create(String.Format(url, Address, Variables.APIkey)); to var wGet = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(String.Format(url, Address, Variables.APIkey))); to get formatting for funky chars in address

Comment: Thanks @KeithL, I tried to add that line but still it returns null addresses to my URL. When i specify the abowe address in a String such as,         string Address = " Beihinger Strasse 160 DE-71726 BENNINGEN GERMANY";
        var wGet = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(String.Format(url, Address, Variables.APIkey))); it does however return a correct XML Get but then my script dont return the longitude and latitude however, So it still seems that it is something wrong with formatting on address....

Comment: You can usually get the XML to be returned directly from a browser window. Make that work first and then transition that to the code.